# How do I capture error messages from ActiveRecord validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm creating a registration form using validation inside the User model such as

```
 validates_confirmation_of :password, :message = "Passwords do not match"
 validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message = "Email in use"
```

and register looks like this

```
def register
@user = User.new(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    redirect_to(:action => 'login')
  else
  end
end
```

I just have no idea how to return these messages to the user once they trigger any of these validations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well You dont have to explicitly do this If your validations fails they errors message is written into the the errors object for that object in your case @user

so Check

`@user.errors.count()`
or
`@user.errors`

To display the error message on the page

You could just iterate over the errors object

## Edited :

```
<% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>

<%= message %>

<%end%>
```

Comment: @user827570 You're welcome. 'Thanks' is a way too much, accepting an answer would be sufficient :(

Comment: I'm no expert, but aren't you missing an `each` method before the do block? `@user.errors.full_messages.each do |message|`